# Irreducible permutations in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n$ be an integer $\geq 2$ , let $\tau \in S_n$ and let $X$ be a nonempty subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Say that $\tau$ fixes $X$ if $\tau(X)=X$, and say that $\tau$ acts irreducibly provided the only nonempty subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ fixed by $\tau$ is $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ itself. Prove $\tau$ acts irreducibly if and only if $\tau$ is an $n$-cycle.
I appreciate any help. 
My attempt:

$\tau$ is irreducible and $\tau$ sends $x$ to $x$, so that $\tau(x)$ has $n$ elements, that shows $\tau$ is an $n$-cycle
But I don't think it right. And I don't know how to go backward <--- from if $\tau$ is an $n$-cycle, then $\tau$ acts irreducibly.
Teach me, please

Comment: Not even close to right. Why is $\sigma=(123)(45)$ not irreducible in $S_5$? It is not a cycle, but $\sigma x\neq x$ for any $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Note that $X$ in the question is subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, not elements of $\{1,2,3\dots,n\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for reply. Please, give me a hint. But is it not that (123)(45) irreducible? is it not that they are disjoint in S5?

Comment: Well, I'm first trying to help you understand the definition. Do you understand why $(123)(45)$ is not irreducible?

Comment: Honestly, I don't. To me, in S5 it is irreducible

Comment: What is $\sigma(\{1,2,3\})$ if $\sigma = (123)(45)$?

Comment: it sends 1 to 2; 2 to 3; 3 to 1 and sends 4 to 5 and 5 to 4. If it applies on {1,2,3} then, the image just have {1,2,3} only, right? so, sigma ({1,2,3}) = (1,2,3). I am willing to learn. Please, give me a link relate to the topic. I won't bother if I get the concept.

Comment: So if $\sigma(\{1,2,3\}) = \{1,2,3\}$, then do you see why that means that the permutation $\sigma$ does NOT act irreducibly.  This is a matter of carefully reading the definition of acting irreducibility and parsing the logic of it.